# Audio not working on WMP and VLC Players but works in the Web and using MPC-HC

Tags: windows-7, audio, drivers, vlc-media-player, windows-media-player

I did a windows update which fails with recovery tool: the issue was solved using a previous restore point and a check disk (CHKDSK) wich deleted many files on windows.

After re-booting Windows 7 / 64 bits. I was unable to play audio file (.mp3) using either VLC player (2.2.4) or windows media player. However, it plays correctly in Media Player classic MPC and also on any browser player (Opera, Chrome, Firefox etc).

```
MPC-HC (Nightly, 64-bit)
------------------------

Build information:
    Version:            1.7.10.252 (e91b41e)
    Compiler:           MSVC 2015 Update 3
    Build date:         Jul  8 2016

LAV Filters:
    LAV Splitter:       0.68.1.31
    LAV Video:          0.68.1.31
    LAV Audio:          0.68.1.31
    FFmpeg compiler:    MinGW-w64 GCC 5.4.0

Operating system:
    Name:               Windows NT 6.1 (build 7601, Service Pack 1)
    Version:            6.1 (64-bit)

Hardware:
    CPU:                Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4200U CPU @ 1.60GHz
    GPU:                Intel(R) HD Graphics Family (driver version: 10.18.10.4358)
```

I have tried different Audio Drivers but none of them solved the issue, but I think it's related to non proper use of codecs.
My audio driver is connexant and I tried official updates (Rollback Driver, update from device manager, update from connexant and from toshiba for my model Satellite L50-B 11G). Below audio driver tried and tested after reboot.

```
1.
Driver provider: connexant  
Driver date    : 11/04/2014 
Driver version : 8.65.38.50    // Audio plays only using MPC

Driver date    : 11/03/2014 
Driver version : 8.65.35.50    // Audio plays only using MPC

Driver date    : 20/08/2015 
Driver version : 8.66.19.52    // Audio plays only using MPC
```

The first two ones are Microsoft signed and the last one is not digitally 
signed.

WMP shows this message:

> Windows Media Player cannot play the file because there is a problem
>   with your sound device. There might not be a sound device installed on
>   your computer, it might be in use by another program, or it might not
>   be functioning properly.

Note: All those Players was installed before having this issue and they were working correctly. The browser is playing sound correctly !

Thanks in advance. I am still struggling with this issue, even BB Flash Recorder and similar applications doesn't record sound !

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you run a System File Check (SFC) scan to repair any missing or damaged system files, see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833 for instructions.

Does the scan find any problems and is it able to fix them?

Comment: I have already done this and tried to re-install audio drivers and run Windows update but didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Ok, but did the SFC scan find any problems and if so, was it able to fix them all?

Comment: Hello , no problems were found !